# Kill LXDE when disconnecting from VNC

Tags: debian, vnc, lxde

I've managed to set up LXDE to start only when I connect over VNC.

But I'm putting together a small web server that has low CPU and RAM.

LXDE is really cool because it requires only a little of that low amount. But it doesn't need to be running 24/7, specially when not connected by VNC.

Is it possible to kill LXDE when I disconnect from VNC? If so, how can I do that?

My system is simply a Debian 8.2 x64 with TightVNC installed.

---

I was suggested to use a cron job to check if the process is running, but I have no idea how to kill LXDE and how to check if VNC is running.

Comment: Your request goes against the usual point of VNC usage. Killing your desktop environment when your connection breaks risks data loss. Why don't you manually exit your LXDE session (if convenient) before closing the VNC connection?

Comment: @FerencWágner Data loss isn't an issue. I can't leave the session because it starts right up again because I'm still connected on VNC. I will be managing almost everything remotelly, without the desktop. But some things are way faster when using the desktop. Data loss isn't a problem since I won't be doing anything besides copying files and moving and editing simple things that can be easily re-done. The usage will be light. Therefore, there's no need to keep the desktop running.